# Java space at start of text file

Tags: java, space, bufferedwriter

I have a program that ask the user for what application it want to open,
this is how the program works:

- the user write what application it want to open in a "inputDialog" example the user write "Open application Notepad".
- the program looks for the word "application" in the text file so the program is sure that it was a application the user wanted to open.
- both the "open application" sentence and the application name  get stored in a text file.
- then does program remove "Open application" from the text file, and then is only the application name visible.
- but always a space comes in front of the application name. Please help me remove the space infront of the application name!!

Here is my code:

```
package Test_Code;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class New_Loader_3 {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        String Test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Test");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Applications/Userdata/tmp/Application.txt"));
         writer.write(Test);
         writer.close();
          int tokencount;
           FileReader fr=new FileReader("/Applications/Userdata/tmp/Application.txt");
           BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
           String s1;
           int linecount=0;
           String line;
           String words[]=new String[500];
                                        while ((s1=br.readLine())!=null)
                                                {
                                                linecount++;
                                                int indexfound=s1.indexOf("application");
                                                                             if (indexfound>-1)
                                                                             {
                                                                                FileInputStream fstream1121221 = new FileInputStream("/Applications/Userdata/tmp/Application.txt");
                                                                                  DataInputStream in1121211 = new DataInputStream(fstream1121221);
                                                                                  BufferedReader br1112211 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1121211));
                                                                                  String Name12122131;
                                                                                  while ((Name12122131 = br1112211.readLine()) != null)   {
                                                                                    if (Name12122131.startsWith(" "))   
                                                                                    {  
                                                                                        System.out.println("Name12122131");
                                                                                    }
                                                                                  }
        String mega = Test.replaceAll("Open application",""); 
        System.out.println(mega);
        BufferedWriter Update_Catch = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Applications/Userdata/tmp/Application.txt"));
         Update_Catch.write(mega);
         Update_Catch.close();
                                                                             }
                                                }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: So [String.trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the user types in `Open<space>application<space>Notepad`. Now when you replace `Open<space>Applicaton` the space before `Notepad` is still left. So I just you use this instead:

```
String mega = Test.replaceAll("Open application ","");
```

Adding a `<space>` at the end of `Open<space>Application` will replace the space too. So now `mega` will be `Notepad`.

Otherwise you could use what you're already using and then call `mega.trim()`

Comment: If it helped you do accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of my answer. Welcome to stackoverflow.